# Instrumental amplifier outputs in 12 lead ECG

Tags: amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier, circuits, biopotential, ecg

[image]

Currently we are trying to build 12 lead ECG circuit, so we just need to know the answers to couple of questions. Why do instrumental amplifiers on given circuit have two outputs? How are they connected to ADCs?

Here's [a link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIeipbjleuY&ab_channel=TexasInstruments)!
of youtube video where this screenshot was taken

Comment: There are ADCs, that have a differential input pair. They are used in this concept. What details do you want to know about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do instrumental amplifiers on given circuit have two outputs?

So that they can send fully differential signals to the ADCs. This allows for the InAmps and the ADCs to be on different boards, and tolerate some common mode difference between them. Even on the same board, you would generally get a better signal and lower noise with a fully differential connection.

> How are they connected to ADCs?

At the block diagram level shown, they are directly connected. That's not a schematic however, there are many components not shown. It might be the case that they are connected directly on the actual circuit, it will certainly function like that. They might be connected with series resistors and a small capacitor across the ADC input to give a bit of lowpass filtering and RF immunity. You might find yourself needing to add such a filter there if you are troubled by RF pickup.

Comment: Thanks for assistance, can you give any ideas how I can understand where the output of amplifier is going? You can also check the Youtube link in the post (source).

Comment: @NikaAbashidze The output of amplifier is going to input of ADC. Nobody is going to watch a youtube video, myself included.